# Set containing midpoints is an interval?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, real-numbers

Let $J\subset \mathbb{R}$ be a set such that if $x_1,x_2\in J$ then the midpoint $(x_1+x_2)/2$ is also element of $J$. I want to see if this is an interval or not. One thing I know is that $J$ is an interval if and only if for all $a,b\in J$ and $x\in (a,b)$ we have $x\in J$.

In that case I belive the claim is not true. For example if we let $J=[0,1]\cap \mathbb{Q}$ then we have clearly the property I stated, but there are the irrationals which are not on the set. In that case by the result I stated $J$ is not an interval.

Is my reasoning correct?

Comment: You should let $J = [0,1] \cap \mathbb Q$. Because otherwise both $x_1 = \frac{\pi}{10}$ and $x_2 = 1 - \frac{\pi}{10}$ are in $J$ whereas $\frac{x_1 + x_2}{2} = \frac{1}{2}$ is not in $J$.

Comment: Thanks @ThePortakal, it is what I meant, that was a typo. It should be $\cap$ rather than $\setminus$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. For $x_1 , x_2 \in J = [0,1] \cap \mathbb Q$ we have $\frac{x_1+x_2}{2} \in J$.

Also, $J$ is not an interval because $0.6 < \frac{\pi}{5} < 0.7$ but $\frac \pi 5 \not \in J$.